# How write following code without regular expression

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, numbers, extract

i wrote the following code for extracting the all no. from the web page & add all of them.but i want to code it without using regular expression so, please Guid me how to do it.
link:http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_361585.html

my code :

```
import urllib
import re
from BeautifulSoup import *

html = urllib.urlopen('http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_361585.html ').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('td')

total = 0
for tag in tags:
# Look at the parts of a tag
      line = str(tag)
      x = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
      if len(x) > 0:
           for item in x:
                total += int(item)

print(total)
```

With out using regex i tried this:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = raw_input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)


tags = soup.find_all('span', text=True)

for tag in tags:
        number=tag.get('class', None)
        total = sum( int(tag.text) for tag in tags )

print ('total')
```

but it having some error: 'NoneType' Object Is not Callable.

guide me how i fix it.

Comment: You should do your own homework...

Comment: i Did that already..i want to know 2nd way

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use regex at all, you can do this easily with bs4 only.
Instead of getting all 'td' and filter their value with regex, you can search for 'span' :

```
tags = soup.find_all('span', text=True)
```

Then you can sum the results :

```
total = sum( int(tag.text) for tag in tags )
```